# run javascript befor page full load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a master page and child pages.
The menu is on the master page.
I get the permissions by Ajax call to hide menu links.

```
$.ajax({

  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "Query.asmx/GetUserPermissions",
  data: "{}",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (Result) {
    Perms = Result.d;
    var pageName = location.pathname.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    if (Perms.indexOf('4') != -1) {
      $("#liCars").show();
    }
    else {
      if (pageName == 'webform2') {
        window.location = 'default.aspx'
      }
    }
  },
  error: function (Result) {
    alert(Result.d);
  }
});
```

So what is the problem?
The problem is if the user type the `url` without menu, the page is fully loaded before it is redirected to default.
I think that is normal because it is on document.ready.
I tried it too outside the `ready()`, but the `li` does not exist... So the hide or show does not work.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should cut the full menu html from html file and use `append();` to show it when you need to . this way it will not show till javascript loads for example:

```
$.ajax({

  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "Query.asmx/GetUserPermissions",
  data: "{}",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (Result) {
    Perms = Result.d;
    var pageName = location.pathname.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    if (Perms.indexOf('4') != -1) {
      $("#mydiv").append('<menu>menu items html</menu>');
    }
    else {
      if (pageName == 'webform2') {
        window.location = 'default.aspx'
      }
    }
  },
  error: function (Result) {
    alert(Result.d);
  }
});
```

Comment: where to put the script

Comment: it doesn't depend on where to put it, it depends on html will be empty until the javascript run.

Comment: so you can put it anywhere.

Comment: this is the li it have resources so dynamic create will not be a good choice <li id="liMap" class="Map" style="padding-right: 85px; display: none">
                                <a href="FrmMap.aspx">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMap" runat="server"  meta:resourcekey="lblMaoResource1"></asp:Label>

                                </a></li>

Comment: it is the li for the menu thats why i can't make it dynamic because it has sever side controls

Comment: you can move the javascript code out in the asp file in script tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144683/discussion-between-to-be-and-maher-khalil).